# Serialise Java Map as [{key: "key1, value: "value1"}, {key: "key2, value: "value2"}, ...]

Tags: java, jackson

I'm going around in circles here because there's about 50 questions on Stack Overflow asking how to get the *default* jackson behaviour... I don't want that behaviour so don't tell me this question has already been answered. Thanks.

I have a simple map `HashMap<String, String>` and need to serialise it into a form that a 3rd party app understands. I need the following:

```
[
  {
    "key": "k1",
    "value": "v1"
  },
  {
    "key": "k2",
    "value": "v2"
  },
  ...
]
```

I do **NOT** want this: `{k1: "v1", k2: "v2", ...}`

Anyone who understands the black art of jackson care to share their wisdom?

Comment: Why don't you convert your map to a map with the required format and then use standard Jackson serialization? It would be even more expressive than using Jackson annotations to customize serialization

Comment: @fps I was just about to fall back to that actually... just seems like boilerplate stuff, would've thought you could tell jackson to serialise a map in this way

Comment: You might create a custom serializer for this, I don't think there's some annotation that could change a map to a list of maps like this. But I would advice against this approach and go the expressive road instead. Let your code clearly tell what it's actually doing: if it's changing the map to a list of maps, just do that. It's no more than 4 lines of code

Comment: @fps Okay then I will take your advice on this one and be verbose. I created a pojo which contains a field of type `ArrayList<ConfigTuple>`. The `ConfigTuple` class contains 2 fields `key` and `value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static class Wrapper {
    String key, value;

    public Wrapper(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Map<String, String> map = Map.of("key1", "value1", "key2", "value2");

    String json = new Gson().toJson(map.entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> new Wrapper(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet()));

    System.out.println(json);
}
```

Output is:

```
[{"key":"key1","value":"value1"},{"key":"key2","value":"value2"}]
```

Comment: Thank you. My mistake was thinking there would be some out-of-the-box way to tell jackson to do this. In future I will not be afraid to create extra pojos and clearly define the structure.